# How can I determine if an element isn't in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this:

```
$.inArray(tld, tldsArray)
```

I would like to check if tld is NOT on the array. How can we say this on jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See if the result is `-1` like this:

```
if($.inArray(tld, tldsArray) == -1) {
  //not in the array
}
```

You should **not** use `if(!$.inArray(tld, tldsArray))` since [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns the *position* in the array, including `0` if it's the first element.

Comment: @Nick, not really, I feel like it's ironic to see someone getting annoyed about something so insignificant

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), the `inArray` method returns `-1` when the element is not found in the array. So simply test the returned value against `-1`.